# Logging DNS requests on a windows DNS resolver

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, logging, internal-dns

How can i log DNS requests sent by clients to a windows DNS **resolver** without using the [debug log file technique](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776361%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

It can be a windows 2008+ only solution

edit 1 - some additional background: i already have a complete infrastructure to gather and correlate my event logs, and would like to know if it would be possible to leverage it without needing to setup another system/agent to gather the debug log.

Answer (score 2):

The debug log is exactly what you should use for this. You'd do well to explain a little more so that we can understand why don't want to use it.

Having said that, you could probably install a network packet sniffer such as [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), set up filters and logging and analyse that some way, but honestly the debug log is really the best way to do this and I'm struggling to think why you wouldn't want to use it.