# Windows DNS Debug Logging Performance Impact

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, logging, debug

Similar to this question, [Logging DNS requests on a windows DNS resolver](https://serverfault.com/questions/415428/logging-dns-requests-on-a-windows-dns-resolver), I am curious how much of a performance hit/impact enabling DNS Debug Logging will have on a server. Per the Microsoft links, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776361%28v=ws.10%29.aspx, they all state that there will be an impact but not how much of an impact.

I realize that the amount of items that you turn on for logging and how busy your DNS server will be are important factors; however, I was curious what an average impact is that one can expect by turning on the logging.

Answer (score 2):

No noticeable impact for my network - Server 2003 R2 virtual machine with ~3000 clients hitting it logging both Send and Receive. It rolls over when it hits the specified size, I keep the files at 500 meg.

I measured query latency before and after and did not see any change. It does hit your disk a bit but it's sequential and easy to cache data.

Comment: Do you forward those log onto a centralized logging server/appliance?

Comment: No, I'm in the process of moving clients off the Windows boxes, 99% of our DNS traffic will be through a pair of Bind 9 servers with only DDNS registrations etc hitting the DCs. Eventually I'd like to but the format of those logs would take some serious sed skills to make easy to read.